# bounding box in osm files

Tags: openstreetmap, convert, osmosis

I have a osm file,i convert it to pbf file by osmosis.but it not convert to .map file.i use this in cmd:

```
osmosis --rb
file=city.osm.pbf -mw file=map.map bbox=34.3635451292,30.0247495993,57.513131979
3,53.2954765066
```

get it ERROR:

```
SEVERE: Execution aborted.
org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.OsmosisRuntimeException: Argument bbox for task 1
-rb was not recognised.
```

what is this?!

My Osm File Bound Tag:

```
<bounds minlat="30.0247495993" minlon="53.2954765066" maxlat="34.3635451292" maxlon="57.5131319793"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The bbox for osmosis should have the order left - right - top - bottom. Note that West of Greenwich has to be negative.

Alternatively, you can write something like

```
--bb left=30. right=34. bottom=53. top=57.
```

to avoid any misunderstanding.

See http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Detailed_Usage_0.44#--bounding-box_.28--bb.29

---

**EDIT**

The Map-Writer plugin has its own definition of a bounding box:

https://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/wiki/GettingStartedMapWriter

```
minLat, minLon, maxLat, maxLon in exactly this order
```

invoked with bbox= instead of --bb

So you have to decided wether you use a bounding box on reading or on writing.

Comment: --mw is true.worked for osm files from osm site.

Comment: i used:
osmosis --rb
city.osm.pbf -mw file=ddd.map --bb 34.,30.,57.,53.
ERROR:
Only one default (un-named) argument can exist per task.  Arguments 3 and 2 have no name.

Comment: the --bb belongs to the osmosis parameters, while bbox belongs to the mapwriter plugin.